# Return code of subprocess.run when using shell pipes

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to understand the return code of `subprocess.run`:

```
>>> subprocess.run('false | true', shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args='false | true', returncode=0)
```

```
>>> subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])
CompletedProcess(args=['false', '|', 'true'], returncode=1)
```

```
>>> subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'], shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['false', '|', 'true'], returncode=1)
```

It looks like specifying `cmd` as a list of strings also sets the `pipefail` shell option:

```sh
$ false | true
$ echo $?
0
```

```sh
$ set -o pipefail
$ false | true
$ echo $?
1
```

I can't find any information about this in the documentation of the subprocess module. I am using python 3.6. Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'], shell=True)
```

When you pass a list of strings to `subprocess.run` and specify `shell=True`, only the first item is interpreted as a command (the remaining items are provided as arguments to the shell). Compare the output of:

```
>>> subprocess.run('echo hello world', shell=True)
hello world
CompletedProcess(args='echo hello world', returncode=0)
```

With:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['echo', 'hello', 'world'], shell=True)

CompletedProcess(args=['echo', 'hello', 'world'], returncode=0)
```

With:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['echo $0 $1', 'hello', 'world'], shell=True)
hello world
CompletedProcess(args=['echo $0 $1', 'hello', 'world'], returncode=0)
```

So what you have there is equivalent to:

```
>>> subprocess.run('false', shell=True)
```

> And do you know why the return codes of subprocess.run('false | true', shell=True) and subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true']) are different?

Because the first runs `false | true`, which is a pipeline. The exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline (in this case `true`). The second call, as discussed here, just runs `false`.

Comment: Shouldn't that mean that the second snippet `subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])` should have zero return code, because the default of shell if False?

Comment: @larsks Thanks, I didn't know that. And do you know why the return codes of `subprocess.run('false | true', shell=True)` and `subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])` are different?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is wrong - I believe that a list of strings gets joined into one (with spaces between) with `shell=True`.  Items after the first are definitely *not* being ignored in my quick testing.

Comment: @jasonhaper I'm pretty sure it's correct. I tested it. If you can prove otherwise, please post that as an answer and I'll delete this one.

Comment: @RedKnite remember that in the shell, `0` means success and `1` (or nonzero in general) means failure. So running `subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])` gives you a `returncode` of `1`, because that's exactly what running `false` returns.

Comment: @b100 compare the return code of `false` and `false | true` in the shell. Remember that `|` returns the exit code of the last command in the pipeline.

Comment: @larsks: [The docs specify the behavior for passing a sequence of `args` when `shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). For POSIX systems, "If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.", so for an `args` sequence, it's the equivalent of using `shell=False`, but executing: `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`. So the list isn't joined with spaces, but neither are the additional arguments completely ignored.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that sounds more reasonable. I've updated the answer to reflect that, and included an example of what it means to be "treated as additional arguments to the shell".

Comment: I think a distinction that I and possibly b1000 hadn't been making is that "|" is not intended to be an argument and when shell=False it is supplied as one to false, which doesn't do anything. I would say that `subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])` is more closely equivalent to `false '|' 'true'` than just `false`

Comment: @RedKnite But it's not.  That's like saying that `subprocess.run(['echo', 'hello', 'world'], shell=True)` would print `hello world`.  It won't. Running `subprocess.run(['false', '|', 'true'])` just runs `false` and does not provide it with any arguments.  If you wrote `['false $0 $1', '|', 'true']` it would match your theory.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Just to confirm, is `subprocess.run('set -o pipefail; ' + cmd, shell=True)` the easiest way to run commands with `pipefail` enabled?

Comment: @b1000 I think so, yes.